# '/etc/.a/kernelupd /etc/.a/.cf --daemonized' Using 100% CPU

Tags: kernel, cpu-load

I found this process which uses all CPU Power:

```
/etc/.a/kernel upc /etc/.a/.cf --daemonized
```

I have not started this myself, what is this?

It seems to be a kernel update, but as I said. I did not start this.
Maybe this is caused by canonical live update?

[image: htop screenshot]

Comment: Sounds very dodgy to me. Kill the process. There should be no `.a` folder, as far as I know, this may be a program that tries to hide itself as a hidden file.

Comment: Well, there is [this](https://cfengine.com/), but you would know it if you used that, wouldn't you.

Comment: Ok, Im not using that software. If I kill the Process, it justs starts again. Also after reboot. what now?

Comment: If it starts again, can you kill its parent process? (Not if it's process ID is 1.)

Comment: how do I fint out its parent process?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep daemonized` , third field is the parent process ID.

Comment: Just killed it with 'killall kernelupd' that seemed to work. but after eboot this probably will start again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85490/discussion-between-jos-and-hag-o-hi).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an XMR mining malware. My server was also hacked to run the same program, which has exactly the same file creation date time as yours.